# Bubble sort Linked list C++

Tags: c++, sorting, linked-list, bubble-sort

I'm having problems with this code. I'm pretty sure it's in the swapping.

The line: `curr->Data() = nextEl.Data()` gives me the following error:

> "expression must be a modifiable lvalue"

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.
Here is the code for my bubble-sort algorithm:

```
class Node
{
private:
    int data;
    Node* next;
public:
    Node() {};
    void Set(int d) { data = d;};
    void NextNum(Node* n) { next = n;};
    int Data() {return data;};
    Node* Next() {return next;};
};

class LinkedList
{
    Node *head;
public:
    LinkedList() {head = NULL;};
    virtual ~LinkedList() {};
    void Print();
    void AddToTail(int data);
    void SortNodes();
};


void LinkedList::SortNodes() 
{
Node *curr = head;
Node *nextEl = curr ->Next();
Node *temp = NULL;

if(curr == NULL)
    cout <<"There is nothing to sort..."<< endl;
else if(curr -> Next() == NULL)
    cout << curr -> Data() << " - " << "NULL" << endl;
else
{
    for(bool swap = true; swap;)
    {
        swap = false;
        for(curr; curr != NULL; curr = curr ->Next())
        {
            if(curr ->Data() > nextEl ->Data())
            {
                temp = curr ->Data();
                curr ->Data() = nextEl ->Data();          
                nextEl ->Data() = temp;
                swap = true;
            }
            nextEl = nextEl ->Next();
        }
    }
}
curr = head;
do
{
    cout << curr -> Data() << " - ";
    curr = curr -> Next();
}
while ( curr != NULL);
cout <<"NULL"<< endl;
}
```

Comment: The code you show doesn't even include the line you say is causing the error.

Comment: Yeah it's because i tried fixing it, but lines of this sort would go in the if statement in the second nested for loop where swapping occurs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort a linked list using bubble-sort?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19522121/how-to-sort-a-linked-list-using-bubble-sort)

Comment: @malat this thread is 2 years old, the thread you linked is 1 year old... so technically that one is a duplicate of mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. You cannot change the value of temp variable returned by a function.

But you can make it work this way..

```
int& Data() {return data;};
```

though this is not good practise. Instead just use the setter you have..

```
curr->Set(nextEl->Data());
```

Comment: I just tried this, and its giving me errors, for "curr" it gives me "expression must be of modifiable lvalue" and for "nextEL" it gives me "expression must have class type"

Comment: Did you add `&` the symbol as shown? Anyway, the second form should still work.

Comment: yes i did, and thanks, i get no errors now! But i think my looping is wrong... i get a .exe problem

Comment: @user1539252- If you hover your mouse below the votes, you'll see a checkmark.. click that.

Answer (score 0):

The statement

```
curr->Data() = nextEl.Data();
```

will never work, you are trying to assign something to the return value of a function. I don't know how you defined Node, but you probably meant something like

```
curr->Data = nextEl.Data();
```

i.e., assign something to a member of Node.

Comment: `curr->Set(nextEl.Data())`, apparently

Comment: Note that assigning to the return value of a function *can* work if the function returns a reference.  Whether that's appropriate is an entirely different matter.

Comment: ups, i didn't see the definition of Node was right there :) Yes, you are right Ben.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
curr ->Data() = nextEl ->Data(); 
nextEl ->Data() = temp;
```

to

```
curr->Set(nextEl ->Data()); 
nextEl->Set(temp);
```