# Add bubble sort code to arrange the list

Tags: c++, sorting

This is my program so far:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    template <class type>
    void display( type list[], int size );

    template <class type>
    void bubblesort( type list[], int size);
```

In my main function I have the lists.

```
    int main()
    {
        const int SIZE = 5;
        string nameList[SIZE] = {"Bob", "Allen", "Beth", "Zebra", 
    "Hamburger" };
        int numberList[SIZE] = {88, 23, 74, 45, 78};


        //display list 1
        display(nameList, SIZE);

        //display list 2
        display(numberList, SIZE);

        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

This is how I display the lists:

```
    template <class type> //template must be included above 
    void display( type list[], int size )
    {
        for( int x = 0; x < size; x++ )
        {
            cout << list[x] << endl;
        }
    }
```

This is where I want to include bubblesort but I don't know how.

```
    template <class type>
    void bubblesort( type list[], int size)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bubble sort Linked list C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570193/bubble-sort-linked-list-c)

Comment: Please be clear on what you have tried and where are you experiencing errors

Comment: @RomanAnanyev what do you mean by that?

Comment: Looks like an assignment where you did not try anything whatsoever.

Comment: Hi Osvaldo, welcome to SO. Please take a moment to look into this to improve you question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @SurajS I dont seem to understand how to input bubble sort that is my only problem everything else seems to work fine

Comment: @OSVALDOTORRES -- *everything else seems to work fine* -- The only thing you did was input and output -- to be honest, this is not an accomplishment of great merit.  The real test, which is to come up with logic to figure out the bubble sort, you haven't written anything.

Comment: Wikipedia has a decent page on bubblesort including several pseudocode examples of how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing bubble sort for integers is straight forward. A simple google of bubble sorting will answer that for you. Strings are slightly different. You would have to grab the first character of the string

```
{
string myString = "cat";

char c = myString[0];

//stringName[0] obtains the first character, since string are basically character array objects, so they can be accessed like a normal array

 }

You can then cast that character to an integer

{

char firstChar = myString[0];

int firstCharValue = (int)firstChar

//or just as 

int firstCharValue = (int)myString[0]

}
```

then youre back to a simple integer bubble sort.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

void bubblesort(type list[], int size)

{
    for(int i=0;i

```
     {
        int flag=0;

        for(int j=0;n<size-i-1;j++)

             {
                    if(list[j]>list[j+1])

                        {
                             int temp=list[j];
                             list[j]=list[j+1];
                             list[j+1]=temp;
                             flag=1;
                        }
               }
        if(flag==1) break;
       }
```

}